# Store Google Maps Marker Info

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to store the title of a clicked on Marker in a global variable using the following code:

```
var selectedUser; //returns undefined 

function attachSecretMessage(marker, secretMessage) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: secretMessage
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
    selectedUser = secretMessage;
    console.log(selectedUser); //Gives title of selected marker
  });

}

function selectedUser () {
    document.write(selectedUser); // returns undefined
}
```

The following is how I am calling selectedUser() in HTML:

```
<div class="selectedUsername">
    <h2><script type="text/javascript">selectedUser();</script></h2>
</div>
```

But I am only getting undefined returned. How can I fix this and be able to store the title of the clicked on Marker and access it somewhere else?

Comment: From where you are calling selectedUser() function?

Comment: @BerozaPaul in a HTML file

Comment: selectedUser()  function is called before the selectedUser variable is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually does write it in the global var. And your console.log proves it. I think that your selectedUser() function executes before the click happens. That's why you have undefined.. Your click callback isn't executed yet. Try doing this (also changing names):

```
var selectedUser; //returns undefined 

function writeSelectedUser () {
    docment.getElementByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = secretUser;
}

function attachSecretMessage(marker, secretMessage) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: secretMessage
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
    selectedUser = secretMessage;
    writeSelectedUser();
    console.log(selectedUser); //Gives title of selected marker
  });

}
```

Comment: This does work but it gives me a whole new page with the result. I want to be able to display the result within the same HTML page.

Comment: Then don't use document.write (that can't be used after the DOM is rendered).

Comment: This is how you are trying to write it on the page. document.write isn't a good option - it overwrites the whole page.. What is the goal you want to accomplish?

Comment: @ArseniiProhorchik The goal I am trying to accomplish is after storing the result, I want to display the result as text within an already establish HTML page.

Comment: Then use document.body.appendChild(result);

Comment: @ArseniiProhorchik that returned the following error : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: @ArseniiProhorchik I don't see anything. See edit of original question to see how I am calling selectedUser in HTML. Maybe I am calling it wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88746/discussion-between-arsenii-prohorchik-and-user1585646).